# R select element by using probability proportional of the elements

Tags: r, list, vector, probability, probability-distribution

is there any simple function or package to select element in the vector or list by using elements probability portions? (in R)

my vector is : c(7,5,3,3,2,1,1,1,1)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.) In the mean time, see `help('sample')`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic sample function can do this. I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve but this is an example:

```r
numbers<-c(7,5,3,3,2,1,1,1,1)
samp<-sample(1:length(numbers), 100000, T, numbers)
table(samp)/ length(samp)
#> samp
#>       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9 
#> 0.29342 0.20677 0.12728 0.12412 0.08271 0.04187 0.04086 0.04175 0.04122
numbers/sum(numbers)
#> [1] 0.29166667 0.20833333 0.12500000 0.12500000 0.08333333 0.04166667 0.04166667
#> [8] 0.04166667 0.04166667
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>